# How to appropriatly use QThreadPool for multiple massive calculation tasks?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

I am facing an issue that should be easy to resolve, yet I do feel that I tap in the dark. I was writing a simple framework which consists of the following classes:

First there is an Algorithm class which simply contains numerical procedures:

```
class Algorithm(object):
.
.
.
@staticmethod
def calculate(parameters):
    #do stuff
    return result
```

Then, there is an item class which holds paths to files, utility and status information. A Worker class subclasses QRunnable:

```
class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self,item,*args,**kwargs):
        self.item = item
    def run(self,*args,**kwargs):
        result = Algorithms.calculate(items.parameter)
        item.result = result
```

And in a Manager class the processes are started

```
class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.pool = QThreadPool()
        self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(4)
        self.items = [item1,item2,...]

    def onEvent(self):
        for i in self.items:
            self.pooil.start(item.requestWoker()) #returns a worker
```

Now the problem: After doing this I notice 2 things:

- The work is done not faster (even a bit slower) then doing it with 1 thread
- The items get assigned the same results! For example result A, which is the correct result for item A, gets assigned to all items!

I could not find much docu on this, so where did I go wrong?

All the best 
Twerp

Comment: Say hello to your new friend Gil:  https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One limitation of the most common implementation of Python (CPython) is that its parser uses a [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) which means that only one thread can be parsing Python bytes at a time.  It is possible for multiple Python threads to be executing C-based Python subroutines simultaneously, and for multiple Python threads to be waiting on I/O simultaneously, but not for them to be executing Python code simultaneously.  Because of that, it is common not to see any speedup when multithreading a CPU-bound Python program.  Common workaround are to spawn sub-processes instead of threads (since each sub-process will use its own copy of the Python interpreter, they won't interfere with each other), or to rewrite some or all of the Python program in another language that doesn't have this limitation.